# CSS Navigation that the menu doesn't expand until clicked to that section

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, navigation, submenu

I'm trying to create a navigation for Wordpress like the navigation in the link below.

[navigation for Wordpress](http://workableweb.com/)

Basically the navigation doesn't expand.  It only shows the sub links if the user is that section.  In the link above an example would be the `"Service"` section.  The sub links only display if you click `"Service"`.  The client accomplished this in Dreamweaver and using Dreamweaver templates and editable regions, but it doesn't work in Wordpress.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have attempted the navigation but the sub links are all displayed like the link below.

http://johnwp.annapolisbook.com/?page_id=6

To everyone that helps, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this 'should' work (you may need to adjust the selectors):

```
.menu ul ul {
    display: none;
}
.menu ul .current_page_item ul, .menu ul .current_page_ancestor ul {
    display: block;
}
```

The key here is to hide all the sub menus `.menu ul ul` and use the `.current_page_item` on the parent element to show the correct sub menu.

Comment: The above solution works really well.  The only thing is if you click a link in the sub navigation it collapses again.  Do you have a suggestion on how to keep it open if a subnavigation is clicked?  For example, if you click "Services" at the link below and then "Design" the link structure remains open.

http://workableweb.com/_pages/serv_redesign.htm

But now on the Wordpress site, if you click the sub links it disappears.  For example, if you click "Lost Fleet Series" and then click "Excerpt from Guardian" the sub links disappear.  

http://johnwp.annapolisbook.com/

Any suggestions?

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect your comments requirements.

Comment: I did see the first comment, so no problem, glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to give the body or a wrapping element the ID of the current page, like so:

```
<body id="services">
```

And the list items a class, that is hidden by default:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>Services</li>
    <li class="nav-section services-section">
      <a href="#">My link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then look for it in the CSS:

```
.nav-section { display: none; }
#services .services-section { display: block; }
```

Of course there are more dynamic ways like checking for each page in PHP, but I consider this a fast, suitable solution

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Unfortunately, I don't think I can really edit the code too much because the code is being driven from Wordpress.  Below is my current CSS and the HTML that Wordpress injects in to the theme.

Comment: If this is wordpress, you can edit the theme freely. While creating a new theme you can only insert the files you want to change, cpy their contents from the default theme, and change what you want; the files not on your theme's folder would be fetched from the default. Also if that's the case, I'd check if each page has a selector you can identify and then try to find how to select the changes you want to make